# Cannot reproduce my travis-ci unsatisfiable requirements julia error locally

Tags: unit-testing, package, julia, travis-ci

I have a Julia project configured to run unit tests in travis-ci and I got a Pull Request from someone else. Tests are passing for julia 0.7, but not for julia 1.1.

I am getting an error related to an unsatisfiable requirement https://travis-ci.org/AlexS12/FlightMechanics.jl/jobs/545855260

```
$ julia --check-bounds=yes --color=yes -e "if VERSION < v\"0.7.0-DEV.5183\"; Pkg.test(\"${JL_PKG}\", coverage=true); else using Pkg; Pkg.test(coverage=true); end"
   Testing FlightMechanics
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package DiffResults [163ba53b]:
 DiffResults [163ba53b] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.0.1-0.0.4 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions 0.0.3 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.0.3
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 0.0.4 or uninstalled — no versions left
```

However, if I test it locally with the following commands I cannot reproduce it:

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ cd julia/test/
xxx@xxx ~/julia/test $ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.1.1 (2019-05-16)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

(v1.1) pkg> activate .

(test) pkg> status
    Status `~/julia/test/Project.toml`
  [b53c057e] FlightMechanics v0.1.0 #master (https://github.com/parthp08/FlightMechanics.jl.git)

(test) pkg> add https://github.com/parthp08/FlightMechanics.jl.git
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/parthp08/FlightMechanics.jl.git`
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/julia/test/Project.toml`
 [no changes]
  Updating `~/julia/test/Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]

(test) pkg> test FlightMechanics
   Testing FlightMechanics
    Status `/tmp/tmpPfzGFd/Manifest.toml`
  [9e28174c] BinDeps v0.8.10
  [b99e7846] BinaryProvider v0.5.4
  [49dc2e85] Calculus v0.4.1
  [da1fd8a2] CodeTracking v0.5.7
  [bbf7d656] CommonSubexpressions v0.2.0
  [34da2185] Compat v2.1.0
  [864edb3b] DataStructures v0.15.0
  [39dd38d3] Dierckx v0.4.1
  [01453d9d] DiffEqDiffTools v0.11.0
  [163ba53b] DiffResults v0.0.4
  [b552c78f] DiffRules v0.0.10
  [b53c057e] FlightMechanics v0.1.0 #master (https://github.com/parthp08/FlightMechanics.jl.git)
  [f6369f11] ForwardDiff v0.10.3
  [aa1ae85d] JuliaInterpreter v0.6.0
  [d3d80556] LineSearches v7.0.1
  [6f1432cf] LoweredCodeUtils v0.3.5
  [e1d29d7a] Missings v0.4.1
  [d41bc354] NLSolversBase v7.3.1
  [77ba4419] NaNMath v0.3.2
  [429524aa] Optim v0.18.1
  [bac558e1] OrderedCollections v1.1.0
  [d96e819e] Parameters v0.10.3
  [85a6dd25] PositiveFactorizations v0.2.2
  [295af30f] Revise v2.1.6
  [a2af1166] SortingAlgorithms v0.3.1
  [276daf66] SpecialFunctions v0.7.2
  [90137ffa] StaticArrays v0.11.0
  [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.30.0
  [30578b45] URIParser v0.4.0
  [2a0f44e3] Base64  [`@stdlib/Base64`]
  [ade2ca70] Dates  [`@stdlib/Dates`]
  [8bb1440f] DelimitedFiles  [`@stdlib/DelimitedFiles`]
  [8ba89e20] Distributed  [`@stdlib/Distributed`]
  [7b1f6079] FileWatching  [`@stdlib/FileWatching`]
  [b77e0a4c] InteractiveUtils  [`@stdlib/InteractiveUtils`]
  [76f85450] LibGit2  [`@stdlib/LibGit2`]
  [8f399da3] Libdl  [`@stdlib/Libdl`]
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra  [`@stdlib/LinearAlgebra`]
  [56ddb016] Logging  [`@stdlib/Logging`]
  [d6f4376e] Markdown  [`@stdlib/Markdown`]
  [a63ad114] Mmap  [`@stdlib/Mmap`]
  [44cfe95a] Pkg  [`@stdlib/Pkg`]
  [de0858da] Printf  [`@stdlib/Printf`]
  [3fa0cd96] REPL  [`@stdlib/REPL`]
  [9a3f8284] Random  [`@stdlib/Random`]
  [ea8e919c] SHA  [`@stdlib/SHA`]
  [9e88b42a] Serialization  [`@stdlib/Serialization`]
  [1a1011a3] SharedArrays  [`@stdlib/SharedArrays`]
  [6462fe0b] Sockets  [`@stdlib/Sockets`]
  [2f01184e] SparseArrays  [`@stdlib/SparseArrays`]
  [10745b16] Statistics  [`@stdlib/Statistics`]
  [8dfed614] Test  [`@stdlib/Test`]
  [cf7118a7] UUIDs  [`@stdlib/UUIDs`]
  [4ec0a83e] Unicode  [`@stdlib/Unicode`]
Test Summary: | Pass  Broken  Total
atmosphere    |   37      10     47
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
coordinates   |   88     88
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
anemometry    |   20     20
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
mechanics     |    9      9
Test Summary:    | Pass  Total
flight mechanics |    2      2
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
pfm           |   16     16
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
mass          |   16     16
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
attitude      |    4      4
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
position      |   16     16
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
aerodynamics  |   16     16
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
aerostate     |    6      6
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
ac: c310      |    8      8
Test Summary: | Pass  Broken  Total
ac: f16       |  223      14    237
   Testing FlightMechanics tests passed
```

Everything works fine and tests pass.

I guess it is something related to my `Project.toml`, but as I cannot reproduce the error I feel lost about what to do. The contributor has also tested in his machine and everything is working for him also.

Why don't I get the same error? What is wrong so dependencies are not properly solver in travis-ci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why don't I get the same error?

What you did locally is not the same as what happens on CI here. On CI tests are run with the package as the active environment, while when you test locally you test from a global environment (`(v1.1)` in this case). You will get the same error if you run with `FlightMechanics` as the active environment.

> What is wrong so dependencies are not properly solver in travis-ci?

The problem is that you have a very outdated `Manifest.toml` file in the repository. The manifest that is used is the one from the active environment.

You can either update the `Manifest.toml` (`pkg> up` when you have the package as the active environment) or remove it from the repo and add it to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
Isn't it a good practice to keep Manifect.toml in the package repo? I think might help reproducibility.

Comment: Personally I think it is best to not commit the manifest until we have something like https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/pull/290 implemented, otherwise you will keep running into the same error as you did here.